# Pumping Lemma for CFL a^n b^m c^o for n<m<o

Tags: pumping-lemma, context-free-language

Let be: L={a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> c<sup>o</sup> | n < m < o, n natural}
Using Pumping Lemma I have choosen: z = uvwxy = a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n+1</sup> c<sup>n+2</sup>
|uv|<=n and |v|>0
=> uv<sup>2</sup>wx<sup>2</sup>y
If vwx is of a's and / or b's it is okay and we would have more a's and/or b's than c's - but if vwx contains only c's it would be element of L.
As far as I understood **all** new words have to be **not** element of L to show that it is not a CFL. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a mix of a's & b's use uv<sup>2</sup>wx<sup>2</sup>y
If we have a mix of b's & c's use uv<sup>0</sup>wx<sup>0</sup>y

Now all words that are created by pumping z are not element of L.